# Spring integration - SpelParseException in gateway

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on some app with spring integration, and I'm gettion Exception

```
Property 'expressionString' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1046E:(pos 24): Cannot find terminating  for string [Sanitized]
```

my gateway:

```
<int:channel id="getProductsReq"/>
<int:channel id="getProductsResp"/>

<int:chain input-channel="getProductsReq" output-channel="getProductsResp" id="getProductsChain">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
        <int:header name="Authorization" expression="@httpSessionService.getToken()"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:service-activator expression="@chainLogger.log(#root, 'FO req for getProductsInfo)"/>
    <int-http:outbound-gateway url="${getProducts.url}"
                               http-method="GET" mapped-request-headers="Authorization,Content-Type"
                               expected-response-type="com.app.GenericResponse">
        <int-http:uri-variable name="code" expression="payload.getCode()"/>
        <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <beans:ref bean="integrationLoggingAdvice" />
        </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

Yup, GenericResponse is a Generic type. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: You miss a single Quote:`="@chainLogger.log(#root, 'FO req for getProductsInfo)"/` i guess

Comment: Thanks Man! You're right!